# Skip value in multiple-value-bind

Tags: common-lisp

A library function returns seven values. I only need the first four and the last one. Is there a more elegant way than:

```
(multiple-value-bind (a b c d e f g)
    (library-call)
  (declare (ignore e f))
  (rest-of-code a b c d g))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [MULTIPLE-VALUE-LIST](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_mult_1.htm) and [SUBSEQ](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_subseq.htm):

```
(defun library-call () (apply #'values '(a b c d e f g)))

(defun rest-of-code (&rest rest)
  (print rest))

(let ((lst (multiple-value-list (library-call))))
  (apply #'rest-of-code 
         `(,@(subseq lst 0 4) ,(car (last lst)))))
```

=> `(A B C D G)`

Answer (score 3):

You can keep a "mvb" look and feel with the [metabang-bind library](https://common-lisp.net/project/metabang-bind/user-guide.html) (a `let` on steroïds which allows more destructing and bindings) and use the `_` placeholder.

Below, we "bind" on a multiple-value with `(:values …):

```lisp
(metabang.bind:bind (((:values _ b) (values 1 2)))
           b)
;; => 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to do this without consing some intermediate structure is what you suggest.  Of course this is easy to define syntax for if it happens a lot.

As an example here's a thing called `mvb` which is like `multiple-value-bind` except that variables whose name is `"_"` are ignored (so this doesn't rely on exporting a symbol `_`).  This relies on [`org.tfeb.hax.collecting`](https://tfeb.github.io/tfeb-lisp-hax/#collecting-lists-forwards-and-accumulating-collecting): it could be redone not to.

```
(defmacro mvb (bindings form &body forms)
  (multiple-value-bind (vars ignores)
      (with-collectors (var ignore)
        (let ((i 1))
          (dolist (b bindings)
            (typecase b
              (symbol
               (cond
                ((string= (symbol-name b) "_")
                 (let ((g (make-symbol (format nil "_~D" i))))
                   (incf i)
                   (var g)
                   (ignore g)))
                (t
                 (var b))))
              (t
               (error "mutant binding ~A" b))))))
    `(multiple-value-bind ,vars ,form
       ,@(if ignores `((declare (ignore ,@ignores))))
       ,@forms)))
```

With this your call would be

```
(mvb (a b c d _ _ g)
    (library-call)
  (rest-of-code a b c d g))
```

Which turns into

```
(multiple-value-bind (a b c d #:|_1| #:|_2| g)
    (library-call)
  (declare (ignore #:|_1| #:|_2|))
  (rest-of-code a b c d g))
```

---

Note that [my `binding` macro](https://tfeb.github.io/tfeb-lisp-hax/#local-bindings-binding) now supports something similar to this, using `nil` as the 'don't bind anything' placeholder:

```
(binding
  (bind/values (a nil b) (values 1 2 3))
  (print a)
  (bind c (+ a b))
  c)
```

`nil` is a nice choice I think because it can't break any existing program since `nil` can't be bound.